# If T follows a t-distribution them prove that U=T^2 follows an F-distribution

Tags: statistics

[image]

Is this correct is there a more elegant way to do this

Comment: This is not only correct but IS the elegant way of doing this. The alternatives are dealing with the densities, the CDF, the moment generating functions, or the characteristic functions.

Comment: Very cool handwriting :) but next time try to use MathJax..

Answer (score 1):

The argument is correct but some of the notation is not standard and I would be somewhat more verbal.

In particular, I've never see the notation $N^2(0,1)$ before.

You wrote:

> If $T$ has a t-distribution then $$ T = \frac Z {\sqrt{W/\nu}} $$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $W\sim\chi^2(\nu).$

It's not clear whether it says $\sqrt{W/\nu}$ or $\sqrt W/n$, so that's a small point to address, which could be consequential as far as the reader's understanding is concerned. A more substantial issue is that I would explicitly mention that the numerator and the denominator are independent. And there's something about which I have a pet peeve: The word "where" should be used for defining notation, but should not be used in effect as a logical quantifier, in this case meaning "for **some**" random variables $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $W\sim\chi^2(\nu).$" That could be the place where you mention independence explicitly, thus phrasing it as "$\ldots\,$for some independent random variables $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $W\sim\chi^2(\nu).$"

Then you could say "$T^2= \dfrac{Z^2/1}{W/\nu} = \dfrac{\chi^2(1)/1}{\chi^2(\nu)/\nu},$ where the numerator and the denominator are independent. Therefore $T^2\sim F(1,\nu).$" And "$T^2=F(1,\nu)$" should say instead "$T^2\sim F(1,\nu).$"